# Detecting gray/smoke regions from a frame

Tags: c++, opencv, color-detection

I'd like to convert this existing color detection from red to a gray color. I grabbed the code from [this project](https://github.com/liberize/flame-detection-system) (Flame Detection System)

I have tried to implement my own algorithm but I think I'm no where near to what I'm trying to achieve. I get the algo from [this link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/36288/how-to-know-grayscale-or-color-img-loaded/?answer=36294#post-id-36294)

Below is the original code fragment with slight modification:

```
void TargetExtractor::colorDetect(int redThreshold, double saturationThreshold) {
    Mat temp;
    GaussianBlur(mFrame, temp, Size(3, 3), 0);
    uchar grayThreshold = 80;

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.cols; j++) {
            if (mMask.at<uchar>(i, j) == 255) {
                Vec3b& v = temp.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
                uchar b = v[0];
                uchar g = v[1];
                uchar r = v[2];
                //if (abs(r - g) < grayThreshold) {
                //  mMask.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
                //}
                double s = 1 - 3.0 * min(b, min(g, r)) / (b + g + r);
                if (!(r > redThreshold && r >= g && g > b &&
                    s >= ((255 - r) * saturationThreshold / redThreshold))) {
                    mMask.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The commented part is my attempt to detect gray regions but it certainly not working for me.

---

### Detecting moving red objects from the original code:

[image: moving red object]

### Detecting moving gray objects:

[image: moving gray object]

Answer (score 0):

Gray color has property of all 3 components being around about the same valued. You can check that all differences between all pairs of 3 color components are below the threshold:

```
if (abs(r - g) < grayThreshold && abs(r - b) < grayThreshold && abs(b - g) < grayThreshold) {
    mMask.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
}
```